# Outgoing call not ringing when using custom ConnectionService and PhoneAccount

Tags: android, service, callback, connection, android-dialer

I'm building an app that hooks on the stock Dialer (Marshmallow API). My goal is to get incoming and place outgoing calls, while getting a handle on the [Connection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Connection.html) objects to manipulate the Connection's methods.

I have registered `PhoneAccount` with the `CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER`.

```
PhoneAccount.Builder builder = new PhoneAccount.Builder(phoneAccountHandle, "CustomAccount");
builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER);
PhoneAccount phoneAccount = builder.build();
telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
```

My account is visible inside the stock Dialer app (Settings-> Calls-> Calling Accounts) and I have enabled it.

I have a Service that monitors Phone State and on `CALL_STATE_RINGING` it calls TelecomManager's `addNewIncomingCall()` method.

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Is Ringing",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_TEL, incomingNumber, null);
        extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_ADDRESS, uri);
        extras.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, phoneAccountHandle);
        telecomManager.addNewIncomingCall(phoneAccountHandle, extras);
    }
    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {.......}
    ...
}
```

My custom [Connection Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html):

```
@Override
public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCreateIncomingConnection called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Connection incomingCallCannection = createConnection(request);
    incomingCallCannection.setRinging();
    return incomingCallCannection;
}

@Override
public Connection onCreateOutgoingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCreateOutgoingConnection called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Connection outgoingCallConnection = createConnection(request);
    outgoingCallConnection.setDialing();

    return outgoingCallConnection;
}

private Connection createConnection(ConnectionRequest request) {
    mConnection = new Connection() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onStateChanged(state);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect() {
            super.onDisconnect();
            mConnection.setDisconnected(new DisconnectCause(DisconnectCause.CANCELED));
            mConnectionsAvailableForConference.clear();
            mConnection.destroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeparate() {
            super.onSeparate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAbort() {
            super.onAbort();
            mConnection.setDisconnected(new DisconnectCause(DisconnectCause.CANCELED));
            mConnection.destroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onHold() {
            super.onHold();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnswer() {
            super.onAnswer();
            mConnection.setActive();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReject() {
            super.onReject();
            mConnection.setDisconnected(new DisconnectCause(DisconnectCause.CANCELED));
            mConnection.destroy();

        }
    };
    mConnection.setAddress(request.getAddress(), TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED);
    mConnection.setExtras(request.getExtras());
    return mConnection;
}
```

Now, both ConnectionService's callback methods get called on incoming and outgoing calls respectively. The problem is, when I go to the Dialer and place an outgoing call (using my `PhoneAccount`) I get the dialing screen (inCallUI ?), with the right caller info being shown (contact name, tel # etc..), but the line doesn't ring in my earpiece and the call is not established (the telephone number that should be receiving the call doesn't ring).

I tried returning `super.onCreateOutgoingConnection(PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, ConnectionRequest request)` in the callback instead of creating my own Connection object, and I get the same behavior.

TLDR: my app communicates with the Dialer, is able to place a call and show the dialing screen, but the phone line doesn't ring and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have been on this for days finding a solution. But after going through the documentation over again it clearly stated that placing outgoing call with a custom **PhoneAccount** does not use the phone sim service to make the call, it the app that will handle all the call operation by itself.

> **CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER**: Flag indicating that this PhoneAccount can make phone calls in place of traditional SIM-based telephony
>   calls.

if you need to transfer data during outgoing call you can use the Bundle to send info to the default call app.

you can read more on the documentation here.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/PhoneAccount
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged#outgoing